# Automatic dotted lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide,tikz-3dplot,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}



\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
 view={135}{30},
 ticks=none,
  zmin=0,zmax=5,
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,
  ymin=-3,ymax=5,
  axis line style={draw=none},
  style={draw=none}
]





\draw[fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5](2,0,4)--(0,0,4)--(0,3,4)--(2,3,4)--cycle;

\draw[fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5](2,3,4)--(0,3,4)--(0,3,0)--(2,3,0)--cycle;

\draw[fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5](2,0,0)--(2,0,4)--(2,3,4)--(2,3,0)--cycle;

\draw[dashed](0,0,0)--(0,0,4);
\draw[-latex](0,0,4)--(0,0,5)node[right]{$z$};

\draw(-2.3,0,0)--(-3,0,0);
\draw[dashed](2,0,0)--(-2.3,0,0);
\draw[-latex](2,0,0)--(3,0,0)node[above]{$x$};

\draw(0,-2.65,0)--(0,-4,0);
\draw[dashed](0,-2.65,0)--(0,3,0);
\draw[-latex](0,3,0)--(0,5,0)node[above]{$y$};
  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to let dashed lines be drawn automatically when the lines are behind surfaces. Shoud I just find those lines and manually draw them as above?

Comment: By "automatically", you probably mean "like a cad software would do", and that, LaTeX is not able to do, as far as I know. Here, the intersections seem not to be so difficult to compute, but with a more complicated drawing, it may represent a lot more calculaltions.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is what I mean. I was looking through calculus book figures and in every example, it had dashed lines whenever behind a surface. So I was wondering if LaTex could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `3dtools` [here](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools). Many thanks to marmot for support this answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
    \foreach \Angle in {60}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,declare function={a=3;h=5;}, c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}, 
            3d/install view={phi=\Angle,psi=0,theta=70},
            same bounding box=A]
            \path
            (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
            (a,0,0) coordinate (A)
            (a,a,0) coordinate (B)
            (0,a,0) coordinate (C)
            (0,0,h) coordinate (O')
            (a,0,h) coordinate (A')
            (a,a,h) coordinate (B')
            (0,a,h) coordinate (C')
            (a/2,a/2,h/2) coordinate (T);   
            \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,O={(T)},
                fore layer=foreground,back layer=background,
                fore/.append style={fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5,thick},
                back/.append style={3d/polyhedron/complete dashes,fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5},
                %edges have complete dashes,
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(A)},{(B)},{(C)}},
                draw face with corners={{(O')},{(A')},{(B')},{(C')}},
                draw face with corners={{(A)},{(B)},{(B')},{(A')}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(C)},{(C')},{(O')}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(A)},{(A')},{(O')}},
                draw face with corners={{(B)},{(C)},{(C')},{(B')}}
            }
            %\path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,C/-90,O/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
            \path[save named path=hull,convex hull of={O,A,B,C,O',A',B',C'}]; 
            \path[save named path=lx] (A) -- (a+2,0,0) node [pos=1.15] {$x$};
            \path[save named path=ly] (C) -- (0,a+1,0) node [pos=1.15] {$y$};
            \path[save named path=lz] (O') -- (0,0,h+1) node [pos=1.15] {$z$};
            \tikzset{3d/ordered paths/.cd,
                hull/.style={draw=none},
                lx/.style={-latex},ly/.style={-latex},lz/.style={-latex}}
            \foreach \Dir/\Line in {{1,0,0}/x,{0,1,0}/y,{0,0,1}/z}  
            {
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{screendepth(\Dir)<0?0:1} 
                \ifnum\itest=0
                \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={l\Line,hull}}
                \else
                \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={hull,l\Line}}
                \fi}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
    \foreach \Angle in {10,20,...,350}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,declare function={a=3;h=5;}, c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}, 
            3d/install view={phi=\Angle,psi=0,theta=70},
            same bounding box=A]
            \path
            (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
            (a,0,0) coordinate (A)
            (a,a,0) coordinate (B)
            (0,a,0) coordinate (C)
            (0,0,h) coordinate (O')
            (a,0,h) coordinate (A')
            (a,a,h) coordinate (B')
            (0,a,h) coordinate (C')
            (a/2,a/2,h/2) coordinate (T);   
            \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,O={(T)},
                fore layer=foreground,back layer=background,
                fore/.append style={fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5,thick},
                back/.append style={3d/polyhedron/complete dashes,fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5},
                %edges have complete dashes,
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(A)},{(B)},{(C)}},
                draw face with corners={{(O')},{(A')},{(B')},{(C')}},
                draw face with corners={{(A)},{(B)},{(B')},{(A')}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(C)},{(C')},{(O')}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(A)},{(A')},{(O')}},
                draw face with corners={{(B)},{(C)},{(C')},{(B')}}
            }
            %\path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,C/-90,O/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
            \path[save named path=hull,convex hull of={O,A,B,C,O',A',B',C'}]; 
            \path[save named path=lx] (A) -- (a+2,0,0) node [pos=1.15] {$x$};
            \path[save named path=ly] (C) -- (0,a+1,0) node [pos=1.15] {$y$};
            \path[save named path=lz] (O') -- (0,0,h+1) node [pos=1.15] {$z$};
            \tikzset{3d/ordered paths/.cd,
                hull/.style={draw=none},
                lx/.style={-latex},ly/.style={-latex},lz/.style={-latex}}
            \foreach \Dir/\Line in {{1,0,0}/x,{0,1,0}/y,{0,0,1}/z}  
            {
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{screendepth(\Dir)<0?0:1} 
                \ifnum\itest=0
                \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={l\Line,hull}}
                \else
                \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={hull,l\Line}}
                \fi}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or for longer axes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground} 
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
    \foreach \Angle in {10,20,...,350}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,declare function={a=3;h=5;}, c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}, 
            3d/install view={phi=\Angle,psi=0,theta=70},
            same bounding box=A]
            \path
            (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
            (a,0,0) coordinate (A)
            (a,a,0) coordinate (B)
            (0,a,0) coordinate (C)
            (0,0,h) coordinate (O')
            (a,0,h) coordinate (A')
            (a,a,h) coordinate (B')
            (0,a,h) coordinate (C')
            (a/2,a/2,h/2) coordinate (T);   
            \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,O={(T)},
                fore layer=foreground,back layer=background,
                fore/.append style={fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5,thick},
                back/.append style={3d/polyhedron/complete dashes,fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5},
                %edges have complete dashes,
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(A)},{(B)},{(C)}},
                draw face with corners={{(O')},{(A')},{(B')},{(C')}},
                draw face with corners={{(A)},{(B)},{(B')},{(A')}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(C)},{(C')},{(O')}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(A)},{(A')},{(O')}},
                draw face with corners={{(B)},{(C)},{(C')},{(B')}}
            }
            %\path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,C/-90,O/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
            \path[save named path=hull,convex hull of={O,A,B,C,O',A',B',C'}]; 
            \path[save named path=lx] (A) -- (a+2,0,0) node [pos=1.15] {$x$};
            \path[save named path=lx'] (O) -- (-a-2,0,0);
            \path[save named path=ly] (C) -- (0,a+1,0) node [pos=1.15] {$y$};
            \path[save named path=ly'] (O) -- (0,-a-2,0);
            \path[save named path=lz] (O') -- (0,0,h+1) node [pos=1.15] {$z$};
            \path[save named path=lz'] (O) -- (O);
            \tikzset{3d/ordered paths/.cd,
                hull/.style={draw=none},
                lx/.style={-latex},ly/.style={-latex},lz/.style={-latex}}
            \foreach \Dir/\Line in {{1,0,0}/x,{0,1,0}/y,{0,0,1}/z}  
            {
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{screendepth(\Dir)<0?0:1} 
                \ifnum\itest=0
                \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={l\Line,hull,l\Line'}}
                \else
                \tikzset{3d/draw ordered paths={l\Line',hull,l\Line}}
                \fi}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this also possible with general surfaces like $z=x^2+y^2$ other than polyhedron?

Comment: I do not  think so. I often do with polyhedron.

Comment: You can post new question at [here](https://topanswers.xyz/). I have an answer form marmot.